# Groovy create list of 2 maps from string

Tags: string, list, dictionary, groovy

Hi i have this `String` which contains `List of 2 strings`. These `2 strings` then contain `2 maps`.

Example `def listStr = '["{"isReal":true,"area":"a"}","{"isRefundable":false,"area":"b"}"]'`;

How can i get from this string list of 2 maps?

Result `[{isReal=true},{isRefundable=false}]`

Comment: I guess you are in this mess, because something/one upstream hands you down a `.toString()` from something more suitable if untouched.  You will have a better time if you find the source of this and fix it there instead of trying to write a parser for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonSlurper` can do the job for you:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

JsonSlurper js = new JsonSlurper()
def listStr = '["{"isReal":true}","{"isRefundable":false}"]'
def res = []
listStr.eachMatch( /"(\{[^\{\}]+\})"/ ){ res << js.parseText( it[ 1 ] ) }
assert [[isReal:true], [isRefundable:false]] == res
```

If you want to have a map in the output, you can trasnform the `res` like:

```
Map map = res.collectEntries{ it }
assert [isReal:true, isRefundable:false] == map
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your response but there are 2 problems . First is listStr is not a list but string which contains list and second i need to have 2 maps not 2 lists, is there a way JsonSlurper can help also with that?